# Copying and pasting ShareLatex into Tex StackExchange editor window

Tags: discussion, formatting

I was going to ask about

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] $a$       \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Effective earth radius [km] calculated from (16).
  \item[] $a_a$ \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm}  An adjusted effective earth radius [km] shown in Figure 8, from (104).
\end{itemize}
```

but copying and pasting makes it look nasty above. What should I do differently?

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste so it does what Cristrian did automatically?

Comment: Just mark the pasted code with the mouse and press either `CTRL-K` on the keyboard or click the `{}` - button in the editor of the question/answer with the mouse

Comment: When I copied my code from ShareLatex and pasted it into the code block here, it was jumbled. I don't know why.

Comment: I cheched the edit.. I think the OP is just pressing the code button (`{}`) and thrying to paste inside there....

Comment: @TegLouis you have first to paste the code and then to select all of it and press the code button : `{}` You can make it an answer and paste test it there.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks! I would not have guessed that.

Comment: Welcome and Welcome by the way  (with both meanings that used to have different word in other languages) :P

Comment: as this is asking about the site mechanics I have voted to move it to meta.tex.stackexchange, feel free of course to post a new question here asking about the actual question.